# Laravel Autenticación con Usuario de Base de Datos

Tags: php, laravel, sql-server

Buen día Comunidad.

Alguna idea para ayudarme a llevar cabo el siguiente experimiento.

Requiero modificar la autenticación de laravel de tal manera que me permita conectar a la base de datos con las credenciales del mismo usuario que se encuentra logueado.

Me explico, al momento de realizar login, la aplicación conectara a la base de datos con un usuario para consultar las tabla de usuarios. Una vez autenticado el usuario las siguientes consultas y ejecuciónes en base de datos seran realizadas con las credenciales de él usuario logueado ya que este ademas de estar registrado en la base de datos tambien tendra un homologo como usuario de base de datos.

Esto con el fin de implementar seguridad a nivel de base de datos, es decir no solo la aplicación si no la base de datos dira quien puede consultar que y que procedimientos puede ejecutar.

Gracias por su tiempo, estare atento a sus comentarios.

---

Nota: La base de datos de conexión es SQL Server 2017 y la versión de laravel 5.8

Comment: Te refieres a saber el usuario registrado o que deberá volver a iniciar sesión o a tener roles

Comment: Me refiero a que durante la sesión del usuario los parametros de conexión cambian ya que serian las credenciales de un usuario de la base de datos, a la vez  este inicia sessión en la aplicación. 

Es decir que la aplicación se conectra a base de datos con las mismas credenciales de login.

Answer (score 0):

No tiene mucho sentido el hacerlo así, pero lo que puedes hacer que es básicamente lo mismo y bien planteado, es utilizar un sistema de tipo SaaS o Multi Tenant... como Laravel For Tenancy... el mismo te hace tener 1 instalación de laravel, multiples inquilinos y cada uno se conecta a una db única o compartida o como lo desees.